# does create table privilege give object privileges like select and delete?

Tags: oracle

I use windows 7 and oracle 11g , so when i created user `test` and give an him  `create table privilege`:

```
grant create table to test;
```

I notice that this user can also do `select,insert,delete` on the table that he created but i don't give him any object privileges.

is create table privilege mean all object privileges are granted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table owner can do *everything* with that table - all DML and DDL actions (selects, inserts, updates, deletes, alters, drops, ... everything).

If you want to let *other users* do something with your tables, then you'll have to *grant* those privileges to them.

Comment: Maybe just clarify -- the user can select, insert, update because he is the table owner and NOT because the user has the `CREATE TABLE` privilege.  If you later revoked that privilege, the user would still be able to access the tables he had already created.  So, the one word answer to the OP's question. as stated, is "no" not "yes".

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant (by saying that "table owner ..."). I've also removed a misleading "Yes" as the first word I wrote, agreeing to your comment. Thank you, @Matthew.